# Failed to boot after interrupted upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, 16.04, upgrade, kernel

Today morning, I started an upgrade for my system (AcerTravelmate 4740) from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, on-line. All the packets downloaded and it started the upgrade. All of a sudden system went power-off on its own. And then fresh boot showed a screen saying kernel panicked etc.(similar to what mention [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758691/ubuntu-14-04-failed-to-boot-after-a-failed-upgrade-to-16-04)).

I read a lot of posts suggesting making a live CD/USB to use 'fsck' based commands .. .. I made a live USB with 13.04 (available at the moment) and followed the procedure, but, all in vain.

I would appreciate a kind help. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you making a _live usb_ with __13.04__, rather than with _16.04_ ? That link you followed said __make usb with 16.04__!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried with 16.04 too...but in vain.

Comment: welcome back, try __version 14.04__.

Comment: I will do that too.... In the mean time, I tried innumerable ways and found that few lines of error have been gone....only this Kernel-panick' lies. Thanks.

Comment: please whatever your trying do update your post with them so we don't offer the same methods again.

Comment: I have now done a fresh install.

Comment: Hope it went well ?

Comment: I accepted that it was taking much time and fresh install was a better step. :)Thanks