# target file system doesnt have requested sbin init

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I tried to upgrade ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, I did the `do-release-upgrade` command after rebooting it froze on a black screen I force shut it, then restart but now I get this error:
[image]
I tried the answer from this [SO question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763211/target-file-system-doesnt-have-requested-sbin-init) but nothing changed, also tried [this](http://pinoy-computing-tips.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-fix-ubuntu-error-no-init-found.html), but the same error.
what can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried "Recovery mode"? If this fails too, try to boot with a rescue CD/DVD. With this you can at least mount your home/data filesystem and do a backup before you try anything else.

Comment: "Recovery mode" result in the same error.

Comment: Then it's time for backup! After that, maybe this question http://askubuntu.com/q/758691/108339 helps, or any of the other questions regarding [ubuntu recover failed upgrade](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+recover+failed+upgrade)